# w3wp CPU usage stuck at 50%, call stack info in Debug Diagnostic is not useful

Tags: asp.net, iis-7.5, w3wp

I saw that CPU usage was too high for my app pool's w3wp process.
Googled out and found articles related to dumps and analysis using Debug Diagnostic tool.

But the analysis only shows up this call stack in "Top 1 thread in high CPU usage":

> System.Web.Hosting.UnsafeIISMethods.MgdIndicateCompletion(IntPtr,
>   System.Web.RequestNotificationStatus ByRef)
>   System.Web.Hosting.UnsafeIISMethods.MgdIndicateCompletion(IntPtr,
>   System.Web.RequestNotificationStatus ByRef)

As soon as I restart the app pool, CPU usage goes back to normal. After few hours of testing different things in website, I noticed CPU usage is back to 50%. I am not sure which scenario is causing this behaviour.

The app is a .NET 4 Razor website running on Windows Server 2008 R2, IIS 7
Whats the next best thing I can do to identify the issues here. 
Few pointers will be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried F12 Developer tools in IE? You can have a look and see which request to the server is taking the longest or creating bottlenecks... it's a start.

Comment: Entire website slows down..not just a particular request

Answer (score 2):

I ended up with some meaningful information using Process Explorer.

Went to w3wp's properties when it was stuck at 50%, looked at "Threads" tab, found a thread consuming close to 45% of CPU and saw its stack information. And there it was, an encrypt string algorithm in my code! :)

Verified this by using dotTrace trial version which gave the same information albeit in a more easy to read fashion.

I will make changes to the encryption algorithm and monitor for CPU spikes 2 more days, just to be sure.